# FBLPromises.framework does not contain bitcode - failing build XCODE 14.2

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, bitcode, xcode14

> '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fqqzmksymhhvlkeeynbylkkvusgy/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'
> does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
> (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
> vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file
> '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-fqqzmksymhhvlkeeynbylkkvusgy/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'
> for architecture arm64

Issue when I change the BITCODE It solve ALL THE ISSUES BUT AFTER THAT BUILD CRASHED ON LUNCH.

Comment: have you solved?

Comment: yes . u solved it. the issue was with ads   service that was disabled from unity. and the second i was changing identifier  in the unity framework to my app identifier. do not change unity identifier